# How to create a zone to drop/select an image for uploading on Ember.js?

Tags: file-upload, ember.js

I have a form and I'm using it to `save()` an ember model to the database.
This model should also have an image, so I want to create a zone like the one below:

[image: drop your image]

User should be able to drag and drop a file from its file browser or selecting it using the blue button.

Also, how do I actually upload the file along with the other model properties?

Comment: https://medium.com/delightful-ui-for-ember-apps/ember-js-and-html5-drag-and-drop-fa5dfe478a9a . made mine based on this...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [EmberDroplet](https://github.com/Wildhoney/EmberDroplet) addon and customize it to your needs (for example you can set file limit to 1 and customize CSS). To upload file you have to specify `url` property, eg:

```
App.XDropletComponent = Ember.Component.extend(Droplet, {
    url: location.origin + '/upload'
});
```

And in your API endpoint (on server side) you could handle file upload + setting image path on model in database (simple string attribute with URL to your image so you can use it later in your application).

Then you could use [`didUpload` hook](https://github.com/Wildhoney/EmberDroplet/blob/master/components/Droplet.js#L553) to refresh your model (this way you get back image URL after upload).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the filepicker.io Ember [addon](http://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-cli-filepicker).

Source code and usage [here](https://github.com/DudaDev/ember-cli-filepicker).

Quick reference below.

Template:

```
{{ember-filepicker pickerOptions=pickerOptions
  storeOptions=storeOptions onSelection='fileSelected'
  onClose='onClose' onError='onError'}}
```

Controller actions:

```
  fileSelected: function(params){
  //save the params.url to your model
  //the image is stored by filepicker on Amazon S3

},
```